# Read API instead of json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api

I have working code in NodeJS. It reads json file and check if the email exist in the json file.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('users.json');
let users = JSON.parse(rawdata);

check email if it exists in Json file
let userData = users.find(obj =>{
   return obj.email == email
})
```

users.json

```
[
    {
     "password": "1111",
      "companyName": "Test2",
      "username": "test2",
      "email": "test2@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "password": "1111",
      "companyName": "Test Company",
      "username": "test",
      "email": "test@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
```

So my question is How can I change json file to API and read it?

I have kind of "database" in Contentfull and the code below can take info and show in console

```
let response = client.getEntries({content_type:'user'})
    .then(response => console.log(response.items))
    .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

that shows in console.log these

```
[
  {
    sys: {
      space: [Object],
      id: '1111111',
      environment: [Object],
      revision: 2,
      contentType: [Object],
      locale: 'en-US'
    },
    fields: {
      password": '1111',
      companyName": 'Test Company',
      username": 'test',
      email: test@gmail.com
      country: 'S',
      city: 'S',
      postalCode: '12334',
      postal: 1111
    }
  },
  {
    sys: {
      space: [Object],
      id: '11111wdsd',
      revision: 2,
      contentType: [Object],
      locale: 'en-US'
    },
    fields: {
      password": '11112',
      companyName": 'Test2 Company',
      username": 'test2',
      email: test2@gmail.com
      country: 'S',
      city: 'S',
      postalCode: '12334',
      postal: 1111
    }
  }
]
```

How can I access and read this?

Comment: Are you asking how to download the file (or the equivalent of its contents) from an external API, or are you asking how to turn this into a server, which will reply to incoming web requests with the information that you have currently printed to the console?

Comment: second. But I think I solve it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this to get the array of fields and use the code you were using while finding from json file.

```
response.items.map(i => i.fields)
```

This will return you response like

```
[
  {
    password: '1111',
    companyName: 'Test Company',
    username: 'test',
    email: 'test@gmail.com',
    country: 'S',
    city: 'S',
    postalCode: '12334',
    postal: 1111
  }
]
```

Your logic can then be like this and you can remove the code where you are reading it from json file.

```
let userData = response.items.map(i => i.fields).find(obj =>{ return obj.email == email })
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I'm a bit confuse where I should put it ... and do I still need to use this function "readFileSync"?

Comment: no. that can be removed.. basically instead of `let userData = users.find(obj =>{
   return obj.email == email
})`

you could do this

`let userData = response.items.map(i => i.fields)
.find(obj =>{
   return obj.email == email
})`

Comment: get this "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" :(

Comment: is your `response.items` not an array? if it is not, then you might need to do `JSON.parse(response.items)` before moving forward.

Comment: let response = .... in console.log shows Promise { <pending> }

Comment: you need to do `.then` to get the actual value in that case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209311/discussion-between-ashish-modi-and-vova).